# Combine AngularJS scope objects from several controllers into a single object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

My app consists of several controllers. Each of them gathers different data into its `scope` object. Now I'm changing the way of dealing with the data so having the data separated is no longer an option (the goal is to have the data sent to a PHP script for PDF conversion).

That being said, I need a way to either have them sent via POST altogether or to have them first combined into a single object and then sent.

I've just found out about angular.extend but I'm unsure if this supports combining objects coming from different controllers and if it does - how and where is it accomplished?

Should it be a new controller, a service or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to complicate things, this is the perfect use for a service (or a factory). Services are singletons, so you won't have to worry about instantiating the same one from each controller - just make a function that will group and gather the data from all the controllers and you're good to go.

Every controller will also have access to this data, so sending it to PHP won't be an issue as well.

---

Simple example:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('CtrlOne', function(myService) {
    myService.sendData('some data');
  })
  .controller('CtrlTwo', function(myService) {
    myService.sendData('even more data');
  })
  .service('myService', function() {
    var gatheredData = [];
    return {
      sendData: function(data) {
        gatheredData.push(data);
        alert('Current data: ' + gatheredData.join(', '));
      },
      getData: function() {
        return gatheredData;
      }
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="CtrlOne"></div>
  <div ng-controller="CtrlTwo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I still don't understand where this `function that will group and gather the data from all the controllers` should be located? I've just created a factory, and the next step would be to include it in all the controllers.
If you could provide more details it'd be great! Thx

Comment: You could inject your factory to each controller that needs to submit stuff, and do it from there. The factory doesn't have access to controllers, but controllers have access to factories.

Comment: I feel so bad that's you're trying to help and I don't understand the whole process. Let's say I have an empty object in the factory and then in my 1st controller I assign that controller's object to factory's object. Then in 2nd controllers I again access the factory object (which at that stage contains data from the 1st controller) and attach its data to the existing factory object. This might work provided the data in factory is persisted between controller calls.

Comment: That's exactly how it should work! And the data persists because the factory is a singleton. Let me write you a quick and simple example.

Comment: Yeah, just make that gatheredData into something more complex, perhaps add another parameter to sendData, so you know the origin of data, etc... but that should do it. You're welcome!